# How to use print() statement to output a value?

Tags: python

I am having trouble getting an equation to return a numerical value using a print statement. I'm not sure if I am using the print statement incorrectly or if something else is wrong with my other code. When I run the code I receive:  in the terminal. This is a homework problem and I'm also new to Python, and coding in general.

Instructions for my task:

- Use the Python file in the left pane.
- Enter a new variable name for the constant 703. In our case, we will use eng_bmi_const as the variable name.
- Create variables for weight and height as in previous labs. You must use 200 for weight and 61 for height.
- Enter a new formula using the new variable for the formula constant.
- Output the value for BMI using the print() statement.

My code is as below:

```
eng_bmi_const = 703
weight = 200
height = 61
bmi = weight/height ** 2 * eng_bmi_const
print(bmi = weight/height ** 2 * eng_bmi_const)
```

The expected outcome: a BMI of 37.8 should be outputted.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just use `print(bmi)` instead of `print(bmi = weight/height ** 2 * eng_bmi_const)`. You already computed it in the previous line and stored the result in a variable.

Comment: Just print(bmi)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already computed the value of `bmi` with `bmi = weight/height ** 2 * eng_bmi_const`, you just need to print it:

```
print(bmi)
```

You can also do:

```
print(weight/height ** 2 * eng_bmi_const)
```

Further reading:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp
- https://realpython.com/python-print/